# Copying one Linked List to another (With below constraints)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have one Sorted linked list and I need to copy it into another linked list following these constraints:

1. Nodes can be inserted at the end of the new linked list only.
2. The new linked list must be sorted after each insertion.

Comment: What makes this hard? Can't you just walk down the original linked list and copy nodes one at a time?

Comment: Rule 1 and 2 seem to be conflicting: the node inserted at the end might eventually need to be inserted elsewhere in order to get the sort order right.

Answer (score 0):

You have a sorted linked list, say `1->2->3->4`. I guess what's expected is not to explicitly sort the list after each insert, so you have two possibilities.

Either you insert each element in the new linked list on your way up, and you get `4->3->2->1` which is also sorted, but not in the same order.

Either you insert each new element while you're on your way down (easy with recursion), and you get the same linked list: `1->2->3->4`.